# How to capture if a google.script.run is being executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to catch google.script.run while it is running, so I can block the user from clicking and activating the function multiple times.

Is something like this possible?

```
while(google.script.run.function()){
alert("Wait for the function to finish")
}
```

Comment: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().withFailureHandler().function()`.  With either `withSuccessHandler()` or `withFailureHandler()` the client code will wait for the server to finish and return

Comment: In my original code I use withSuccessHandler(). I'm trying to block the client from clicking on a button and calling the function several times

Comment: Attach it to a button and disable the button in the onClick event

Comment: When the function is called the button will be disabled, and after it is called activate the button again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling a button:

```
function lfunko() {
  return "Button is disabled"
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  const html = '<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" onclick="myfunk();" /><div id="msg"></div><script>function myfunk(){document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((msg) => {document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;}).lfunko();}console.log("Code");</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Sample Dialog")
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used @Cooper suggestion and deactivated the client click button, and after the function ends I activate it again. Getting like this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">BUTTON</button>
     <?!= include('javascript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript.html

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",click);

function click(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(table).doSomething();
document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
}

function table() {
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled=false;
}
```

code.gs

```
 function doSomething(){ 
  Logger.log("Hello");
}
```